# Not able to set SwipeFlingAdapterView from array adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, swipe, android-json

i have use the `https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards` and it works perfect if data is static but it is not working with `AsyncTask`

Now i want to bind the adapter with json data. but it is not worked.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context context;

    private ArrayList<Productp> al;
    private ArrayAdapter<Productp> arrayAdapter;

    SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer;

    ImageView img_product;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    private static String url_all_products = "http://www.example.com/prod.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "url";

    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
                false);
        context = getActivity();

        initUI(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void initUI(View view) {

        flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) view.findViewById(R.id.frame);


        new Loaditems().execute();


    }

    class Loaditems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("range", "1"));

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET",
                    params);

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    al = new ArrayList<Productp>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        Productp pp = new Productp();

                        pp.portal = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                        al.add(pp);
                    }
                } else {

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            arrayAdapter = new ProductAdpater(context, al);
            flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        }
    }
```

adapter method:

```
    private class ProductAdpater extends ArrayAdapter<Productp> {

        Context mContext;

        public ProductAdpater(Context context, List<Productp> items) {
            super(context, R.layout.row_homeview, items);

            try {
                this.mContext = context;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return al.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (view == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_homeview, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.addviewimage);

                view.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.imgIcon,
                    al.get(position).portal);
            return view;
        }

        class ViewHolder {

            ImageView imgIcon;

        }

    }

    }
```

productp class:

```
public class Productp  {


    public String portal="";
}
```

When i run the above code. it will display nothing.

Even this code run successfully but not bind the data to the adapter.

There are no error show in logcat.

I have also `debug` the code.

```
the execution exit from 

public ProductAdpater(Context mcontext, ArrayList<Productp> items) {
            super(mcontext, R.layout.row_homeview, items);

            try {
                context = mcontext;
                // this.list = items;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

It it not execute the getView method

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {}
```

How can i solved this ?

Comment: Try extending `BaseAdapter` once instead of `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Tried that already. But still not able to bind data.

Comment: Okay. And are you sure `items` array is not empty and atleast has size > 1?

Comment: Yes i have debug the whole code. it is not empty.
When i wrote the whole coding into `onPostExecute` instead of `doInBackgroud` then it is working. But when i write the code into `doInback` then it not working.

Comment: @AbhishekV check my update answer. :-) i have solved it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have solved this.

I have just put the - `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` onPostExecute.

My new updated code on onPostExecute :

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            arrayAdapter = new ProductAdpater(context, al);
            flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

It is done.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to notify the updated data set to the adapter

by using

notifyDataSetChanged();

notifyDataSetInvalidated()

Comment: Yes its fine i just give you the explanation for calling

notifyDataSetChanged();

notifyDataSetInvalidated()

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked **dependancies**? in build.gradle?

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
}`

import these lines in your build.gradle(app) and most probably you will be fine